# List erase iterator out of range

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following code:

```
static std::map<int,int> myFunction(std::list<int>& symbols){
    std::map<int,int> currCounts;
    std::map<int,int> payHits;
    for (std::list<int>::iterator l_itr = symbols.begin(); l_itr != symbols.end(); ++l_itr){
        myFunction_helper(*l_itr, l_itr, symbols, currCounts, payHits, 0);
    }
    return payHits;
}

static inline void myFunction_helper(int next, std::list<int>::iterator& pos, std::list<int> remainingSymbols, std::map<int,int> currCounts, std::map<int,int>& payHits, int i){
    currCounts[next] = currCounts.count(next) > 0 ? currCounts[next] + 1 : 1;
    remainingSymbols.erase(pos);
    if (i < numTiles && remainingSymbols.size() > 0){
        if (currCounts[next] == hitsNeeded[next]){
            int pay = symbolPays[next];
            payHits[pay] = payHits.count(pay) > 0 ? payHits[next] + 1 : 1;
        }
        else{
            for (std::list<int>::iterator l_itr = remainingSymbols.begin(); l_itr != remainingSymbols.end(); ++l_itr){
               myFunction_helper(*l_itr, l_itr, remainingSymbols, currCounts, payHits, i+1);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        payHits[0] = payHits.count(0) > 0 ? payHits[0] + 1 : 1;
    }

}
```

It is supposed to take a set of values and given some requirements (numTiles (int), hitsNeeded (a map of symbols and number of times they need to be chosen to win)).  My code builds on visual studios (most recent version), but when I try executing it I get the error "list erase iterator out of range" the first time the myFunction_helper is called. How do I avoid this? I purposefully passed the remainingSymbols by value so that I can modify it without affecting other recursive stack frame members. How do I fix this and whyis this raising an exception?

---

## Solution

Remove the iterator from the arguments. Then as you iterate you use the following snippet of code:

```
int next = *l_itr;
l_itr = symbols.erase(l_itr);
myFunction_helper(next, remainingSymbols, currCounts, payHits, i+1);
symbols.push_front(next);
```

And similarly for the outer function. Pushing the element to the front doesn't disrupt the iteration over the list and allows for what I want (pushing to the front is super cheap on lists too).

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the Comments below. This is a crap answer because we don't know enough about the business case to suggest a good solution. I'm leaving an edited version it here because I just reverted the vandalized question and it does explain why the attempt failed.

## Why This is raising an exception

`std::list<int> remainingSymbols` is pass by value, so `pos` is no longer relevant. It refers to the source `list`, not the copy of the source list in `remainingSymbols`. Using an iterator for one `list` in another, even a copy, is fatal.

## solution

The common solution is to solution is to pass `remainingSymbols` by reference: `std::list<int> & remainingSymbols`, but since this will break backtracking, you can't do that.

Instead you will have to pass a different identifier for the position, perhaps the index. Unfortunately interating and re-iterating a `list` is an expensive task that almost always outweighs the quick insert and delete benefits of a `list`.

Comment: @Fancypants753 Be careful with what you selecting as answer, you will have issues passing container by reference - you will delete elements in it while iterating

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use iterator from one container with another one, you could use offset instead, but that would be very ineffective with `std::list`. Additionally using`std::list` with `int` is not a good idea in general - your data is small and most probably you use at least twice more memory for maintaining list items than data itself plus cache misses. You better use `std::vector<int>` and pass offset, not iterator. Additionaly with `vector<>` you can use move erase idiom but even deleting `int` in middle of vector is relatively cheap, most probably less expensive than cost of jumping of `std::list` nodes.

Comment: deleting from a list is better in terms of data structures than a vector, but I agree I could use 1 byte types to store this info instead of ints but thats not really the problem I care baout

Comment: You  misunderstood, `std::list` node has 2 pointers as it is double linked list, so you have one `int` and 2 pointers per node for storing `int` there. And you can easily delete `int` from `vector` even more efficient than in `std::list` - swap it with last one and do `pop_back()`

Comment: @Fancypants753 You might want to give [Stroustrup’s piece on Are lists evil?](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists) a read before you put too too much faith in the glories of O(1) removal from a linked list.

Comment: @user4581301 the point is i don't need to iterate quickly over my list, there are only so many nodes in my list before the algorithm becomes useless anyways. In addition, vector iteration wouldnt be ideal using the method that I implemented : I first take the value returned by the iterator and store it, then i remove it from the list, pass the list to the recursive function, and then push the extracted element to the front to not raise any errors with the iteration. The act of putting it back into the front would be very expensive for vectors, as every other element has to be reallocated

Comment: @user4581301 so i guess in contexts where i have to iterate over a large list youre right, but thats obvious. Also I'm not even sure that vectors allow for modification during iteration due to the contiguity of the memory? (this might be completely wrong)

Comment: @user4581301 except if vectors allow for removal at the location and reinsertion at the same location without raising any errors in a loop, then I'd use a vector.